# Backbone route won't fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using coffeescript to power backbone and the initialize alert won't fire. Console shows no errors.

I can't seem to point as to what is the problem in this case.

```js
class Railsbook.Routers.Users extends Backbone.Router
routes:
    '': 'index'
    'users/:id': 'show'
    
    index: ->
        alert 'home page'
        
    show: (id) -> 
        alert "#{id}"
        
        
        // This is the app code
        
        window.Railsbook =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: -> 
      new Railsbook.Routers.Users()
      Backbone.history.start()
      
      
$(document).ready ->
    Railsbook.initialize()
```

edit in: this is my code, translated to js http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Railsbook.Routers.Users%20extends%20Backbone.Router%0Aroutes%3A%0A%20%20%20%20''%3A%20'index'%0A%20%20%20%20'users%2F%3Aid'%3A%20'show'%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20index%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%20'home%20page'%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20show%3A%20-%3E%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%23And%20my%20app%20file%0A%0A%0A%0A%0Awindow.Railsbook%20%3D%0A%20%20Models%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20Collections%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20Views%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20Routers%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20initialize%3A%20-%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20Railsbook.Routers.Users()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Backbone.history.start()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%24(document).ready%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Railsbook.initialize()%0A%0A%0A

Comment: Is the the real indentation in your CoffeeScript?

Comment: What do you mean? I copied my code verbatim

Comment: So that is exactly what your CoffeeScript code looks like in your editor? CoffeeScript code structure is based on indentation so your `routes` property isn't even inside your `Railsbook.Routers.Users` class. Go to http://coffeescript.org, use the **TRY COFFEESCRIPT** tab, and see what CoffeeScript thinks of your router.

Comment: I copied how it looks in my browser o_O but okay , trying.

Comment: So nope, it seems fine https://gyazo.com/897616064069f7c761dc684823c8f596

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my indentation was wrong.

```js
class Railsbook.Routers.Users extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'
    'users/:id': 'show'
    
  index: ->
    console.log('penis')
        
    show: ->
```

Changing it to this (routes 2 spaces, and each route is 2 spaces) made it work